# Setting React project inside Nodejs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok, I have a regular Nodejs project created, then I need to put in public, a Reactjs project to start working on.

I want to use React with ES6 and Webpack.

I went to public folder in my terminal, then, from there I started installing the packaged I need with npm, but I don't see anything new in my public folder.

A new package.json should be created? Then, what should I do in order to run my project?

Comment: This question is much too broad for SO. To give you a hand, though, I'll say the following. You are using Node already, so you don't want two node projects - just one with one `package.json` with all dependencies for client and server. Then you'll need to configure webpack to build React to your specific project needs - there are thousands of resources on the Internet to help with this. Then your built files can be served by your Node backend, but that procedure will vary based on your server framework and webpack details.

Comment: This question isn't very clear.

Comment: I would take one step at a time and try to just get React working, and once that's working add in Webpack and Babel for ES6. Check out https://github.com/petehunt/react-howto

Answer (score 0):

Very broad question.  Take a look at Dan Abramov's starter kit for this: [React-hot-boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate)

Comment: Updated for React Transform https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate (I think webpack-dev-server is deprecated)